# JS Convert a list as string in JS into JSON format - is that possible?

Tags: javascript, json, string, build

In JS my variable is filled with these informaiton:

```
url=http://localhost
quality=100
tag="4.4, 5.5"
```

I would like to convert this over JS to JSON format - Something like this:

```
"result": {
    "url": "http://localhost",
    "quality": "100",
    "tag": "4.4, 5.5",
}
```

How is it possible to convert this information to JSON format?

---

**HTML**

```
<textarea cols="100" rows="10" id="textarea_one"></textarea>
<textarea cols="100" rows="10" id="textarea_two"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
var objLoadHTML = document.getElementById('textarea_one');
var strContent = objLoadHTML.value;


var Reg = /(?:(\w+)=([^\n\r]+))*/gm;
var match = Reg.exec(strContent);

while (match != null) {
    document.getElementById('textarea_two').innerHTML += match;
    match = Reg.exec(strContent);
}


document.getElementById('textarea_two').innerHTML = match;
```

Comment: You could use a regex, regex101 is a good resource for that

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like

```
/(?:(\w+)=([^\n\r]+))*/gm
```

This would return the keys and values for your example.

Comment: Doesn't work... the result is -> **' '** Do you have a fiddle example?

Comment: I have edited my quesiton - please check my code. You can test it on jsfiddle

Comment: You have to loop over the regex to find all matches

Comment: Updated my question - same effect, the result appears now multiple times...